# How to show null value with NumericFilter in EasyAdmin

Tags: php, symfony, easyadmin

I've got a field 'shopSurface' which is nullable and not required.
In EA I added a NumericFilter:
`NumericFilter::new('shopSurface', 'shop_surface')`.
If I want all the entries which have not `shopSurface` I look for `equal to` and I leave empty the field but nothing appear, the list is empty while I have some.

Do you know a way to make it appear ?

EDIT

This is how I did :

```php
public function apply(QueryBuilder $queryBuilder, FilterDataDto $filterDataDto, ?FieldDto $fieldDto, EntityDto $entityDto): void
    {
        $alias = $filterDataDto->getEntityAlias();
        $property = $filterDataDto->getProperty();
        $comparison = $filterDataDto->getComparison();
        $parameterName = $filterDataDto->getParameterName();
        $parameter2Name = $filterDataDto->getParameter2Name();
        $value = $filterDataDto->getValue();
        $value2 = $filterDataDto->getValue2();

        if (ComparisonType::BETWEEN === $comparison) {
            $queryBuilder->andWhere(sprintf('%s.%s BETWEEN :%s and :%s', $alias, $property, $parameterName, $parameter2Name))
                ->setParameter($parameterName, $value)
                ->setParameter($parameter2Name, $value2);
        } else {
            $queryBuilder->andWhere(sprintf('%s.%s %s :%s', $alias, $property, $comparison, $parameterName))
                ->setParameter($parameterName, $value);
        }

        if (ComparisonType::EQ === $comparison && '' === $value){
            $queryBuilder->andWhere(sprintf('%s IS NULL', $alias));
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have 2 solutions :

- Add a NullFilter in addition to your NumericFilter to show null values (all built-in filters are avalables [here](https://symfony.com/bundles/EasyAdminBundle/current/filters.html#built-in-filters))

OR

- Add your custom filter like that (doc [here](https://symfony.com/bundles/EasyAdminBundle/current/filters.html#custom-filters)).

If you need some help do not hesitate.

Comment: By the way I'm wondering how you can add a NullFilter into a NumericFilter, I found nothing in the doc

Comment: you can't add a NullFilter into a NumericFilter but you can add both of them separately or make your own filter to do that as you want @tristan